# Symfony render controller exception template ("")

Tags: symfony, twig

I tried to render a controller inside twig. I follow the documentation "Embedding other Controllers".

I constantly get an exeption with the method render(controller()): 
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("")

In my template.html.twig

```
{{ render(controller('MyBundle:User:logo')) }}
```

In my controller

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function logoAction()
    {        
        return $this->render('MyBundle:User:logo.html.twig', []);   
    }
}
```

It work well if I use in my template

```
{% render url('logo') %}
```

With the route

```
logo:
    pattern:  /logo
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:User:logo }
```

But I want to use render(controller())

What do I do wrong?

Edit, add more info about exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("") in MyBundle:My/Dashboard:dashboard.html.twig at line 51.

500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime 1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »

[2/2] Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("") in MyBundle:My/Dashboard:dashboard.html.twig at line 51.   -

in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 7378   - } catch (Twig_Error $e) { throw $e; } catch (Exception $e) { throw new Twig_Error_Runtime(sprintf('An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("%s").', $e->getMessage()), -1, $template->getTemplateName(), $e); } } elseif (false !== $parent = $this->getParent($context)) { $parent->displayBlock($name, $context, array_merge($this->blocks, $blocks), false); at Twig_Template
->displayBlock ('body', array('preset' => array('date' => '2015-03-31'),... 1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:    -

in app/cache/dev/appDevUrlMatcher.php at line 632   -
        }
        throw 0 < count($allow) ? new MethodNotAllowedException(array_unique($allow)) : new ResourceNotFoundException();
    } } at appDevUrlMatcher ->match ('/_fragment')  in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 3278   + at Router ->match ('/_fragment')
```

Edit2 dashboard.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-random" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <b>{{ "Request"|trans }}</b>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <form role="form" action="{{ path('dashboard', {'idDbd': idDbd}) }}">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    {{ render(controller('MyBundle:User:logo')) }}
                </div>
                {% include 'MyBundle:My/Request:request_edit.html.twig' %}
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>      
    (...)
```

Comment: what is your actual template path ? e.g `/src/MyBundle/Resources/views/User/logo.html.twig`

Comment: /src/CompanyModule/MyBundle/Resources/views/User/logo.html.twig

Comment: @Alexandre can you please give the second exception. That one actually explains what's going wrong. Or maybe the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @WouterJ done in the stack description... thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: from your stracktrace seems the problem is elsewhere, can you post the `Dashboard:dashboard.html.twig` files indicating the line 51?

Comment: i am not sure if you can use {{ render(controller('MyBundle:User:logo')) }} like that, i think you should use {% render(controller('MyBundle:User:logo')) % }

Comment: @NawfalSerrar http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#templating-embedding-controller

Comment: @Matteo done in stack description

Comment: @Alexandre have you tried to put it in `app/Resources/views/Bundle/User` to test the scope ?

Comment: @Heah it doesn't make any differences. By the way I would like to remind that it work with using the method render url, so why not render controller?

Comment: @Heah I wanna render a controller not a view, I don't get it...?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the `controller()` notation for subrequests, you need to enable the special FragmentListener which will be able to handle such subrequests.

You need to have the config for it in your config.yml file. This is done by default in new Symfony project: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/7311e7065bea8986f8eb2e95ab9dd4a55ce95ae2/app/config/config.yml#L31
Check whether you have this line in your own project