# Symfony - Twig render controller exception does not redirect to error page

Tags: php, symfony, exception, controller, twig

I have a Symfony project with multiple layouts. Some of them loads a header using:

```
{{ render( controller("AppBundle:Partial:header") ) }}
```

The header contains some user data, that at some point threw a `Twig_Error_Runtime` exception (on every page).

Since the header was also used on the custom error pages, a loop was created and it ran out of memory. Obviously that happened on `prod` environment only, since `dev` does not use the custom error pages.

I created a route to test the header controller:

```
/**
 * Header partial
 * 
 * @Route("/header", name="header")
 *
 */
public function headerAction(Request $request) {
    [...]
    return $this->render(self::PARTIAL_BASE_PATH . "/_header.html.twig", $data);
}
```

If I access the route `/header` it correctly displays the custom error page.

I removed the header with user data from the error pages, hoping to fix the problem, but now it displays the initial page, with no header whatsoever. The error log says:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[IRRELEVANT-ERROR-MESSAGE]").") in "[PROJECT-PATH]/partial/_header.html.twig" at line 49." at [PROJECT-PATH]/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php line 396 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Runtime(code: 0): An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"[IRRELEVANT-ERROR-MESSAGE]\").\") in \"[PROJECT-PATH]/partial/_header.html.twig\" at line 49. at [PROJECT-PATH]/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:396, [IRRELEVANT-ERROR-MESSAGE]. at [PROJECT-PATH]/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/MessageSelector.php:81)"} []
```

So, it fails to render the header, due to the exception, but instead of redirecting to custom error page, it logs the error and displays nothing.

Of course, I fixed the error and now it works, but I wonder how can I fix this behaviour. I think Twig should redirect to the error page if a rendered controller misbehaves.

Also, I wonder why did it looped before, if nothing is rendered in the header area?

Symfony version: 2.7.10

Twig: 1.24.0

Comment: Why don't you use an include for your header ?

Comment: Good question, I forgot to mention that. :) Because there was a lot of logic that needs to be computed to render the header, beside user data, and it seemed a better approach to have it all in one action in my `PartialController` instead of building a helper method in `DefaultController` that would be called in every action that renders that specific header. Most likely I can change the approach to use `include`, but that won't solve the problem that, when you use `render` `controller` in Twig, you might get unexpected results. That's what's bothering me right now. Thanks!

Comment: It it the same with a blank custom error page ? Like `<h1>error page</h1>` , just to see id you have the same error.

Comment: Retested and confirmed, on `prod` the header is missing, on `dev` I get the Symfony error page.

Comment: Found another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045841/symfony-render-controller-exception-template that does not look like it was solved and the answer does not help. The line `fragments: ~` is already in my `config.yml`.